# Android DB row delete() with while loop

Tags: android, sqlite, boolean, delete-row

I've picked up this piece of code that i'm trying understand and work into my app it should delete a row from a parent table and any rows on a child table its related too i don't fully understand it and eclipse is throwing an error in the while loop, i understand the error but not exactly how the person was getting it to work

```
public boolean removeRow(int paramInt, String paramString)
{
  int i = 1;
  if (paramString.equals("nameTable"))
  {
   SQLiteDatabase localSQLiteDatabase1 = this.db;
    String str1 = "name_ref_ID=" + paramInt;
    int j = localSQLiteDatabase1.delete("itemTable", str1, null);
    SQLiteDatabase localSQLiteDatabase2 = this.db;
    String str2 = "names_id=" + paramInt;
    if (localSQLiteDatabase2.delete(paramString, str2, null) <= 0);
  }
  while (true)
  {
    return i;// shows errror here as its not returning a bool
    i = 0;
    continue;
    if (paramString.equals("itemTable"))
    {
      SQLiteDatabase localSQLiteDatabase3 = this.db;
      String str3 = "item_id=" + paramInt;
      if (localSQLiteDatabase3.delete(paramString, str3, null) > 0)
      continue;
      i = 0;
      continue;
    }
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

too me it seems the return is out of place and and will keep the rest of the loop from being executed.

Comment: Sorry but I've voted to close this as it's not a real question. I realise you wan't to understand how that code works but, simply, it makes little sense. Using `while(true)` without a way of leaving will cause an infinite loop and, as you already pointed out, the return type is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the code would ever work for the person you got it from as he is returning i witch is a INT and his function states he should return a boolean (that's why eclipse is giving you the error).

Also the function will stop running as soon as it hits return. So when the while loop start it will emediatly stop again. Also keep in mind that a while(true) loop isn't really good practice. Basically you create a endless loop and put in some tricks to break out of it again.

To delete a row and all rows of the child table I recommend using two query's. First a delete query on the child table while using a [Inner query](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php) for your where statement. And then another delete on your parent table.

Comment: hmm very good idea can an inner query be used in delete() convenience method if so can you toss up an example?

Comment: Yes you can, there is a example posted here [link](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/delete-statement/delete-with-subqueries.php)